# Python: for a list of lists, get mean value in each position

Tags: python

I have a list of lists:

```
list_of_lists = []
list_1 = [-1, 0.67, 0.23, 0.11]
list_2 = [-1]
list_3 = [0.54, 0.24, -1]
list_4 = [0.2, 0.85, 0.8, 0.1, 0.9]
list_of_lists.append(list_1)
list_of_lists.append(list_2)
list_of_lists.append(list_3)
list_of_lists.append(list_4)
```

The position is meaningful. I want to return a list that contains the mean per position, excluding -1. That is, I want:

```
[(0.54+0.2)/2, (0.67+0.24+0.85)/3, (0.23+0.8)/2, (0.11+0.1)/2, 0.9/1]
```

which is actually:

```
[0.37, 0.5866666666666667, 0.515, 0.10500000000000001, 0.9]
```

How can I do this in a pythonic way?

EDIT:

I am working with Python 2.7, and I am not looking for the mean of each list; instead, I'm looking for the mean of 'all list elements at position 0 excluding -1', and the mean of 'all list elements at position 1 excluding -1', etc.

The reason I had:

```
[(0.54+0.2)/2, (0.67+0.24+0.85)/3, (0.23+0.8)/2, (0.11+0.1)/2, 0.9/1]
```

is that values in position 0 are -1, -1, 0.54, and 0.2, and I want to exclude -1; position 1 has 0.67, 0.24, and 0.85; position 3 has 0.23, -1, and 0.8, etc.

Comment: You should look into list comprehensions. Something like `[sum(l)/len(l) for l in list_of_lists]` combined with a filter to remove whatever specific things you don't want would be a good start.

Comment: @ap And the magic `zip` of course.

Comment: @ap Thanks but it's position-wise, not list-wise. `sum(l)/len(l) for l in list_of_lists]` would give me the mean for each list, which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the 'position' to mean position within the main list. You'd want to use `zip` as per bipll's suggestion for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a vectorised `numpy`-based solution.

```
import numpy as np

a = [[-1, 0.67, 0.23, 0.11],
     [-1],
     [0.54, 0.24, -1],
     [0.2, 0.85, 0.8, 0.1, 0.9]]

# first create non-jagged numpy array
b = -np.ones([len(a), max(map(len, a))])

for i, j in enumerate(a):
    b[i][0:len(j)] = j

# count negatives per column (for use later)
neg_count = [np.sum(b[:, i]==-1) for i in range(b.shape[1])]

# set negatives to 0
b[b==-1] = 0

# calculate means
means = [np.sum(b[:, i])/(b.shape[0]-neg_count[i]) \
         if (b.shape[0]-neg_count[i]) != 0 else 0 \
         for i in range(b.shape[1])]

# [0.37,
#  0.58666666666666667,
#  0.51500000000000001,
#  0.10500000000000001,
#  0.90000000000000002]
```

Comment: One problem with this answer: if `b.shape[0]-neg_count[i]` is 0, then this returns `nan` in that space. I'd prefer it to return `-1` in that case. Here is the revised version:  `means = [np.sum(b[:, i])/(b.shape[0]-neg_count[i]) if (b.shape[0]-neg_count[i]) != 0 else -1 for i in range(b.shape[1])]`

Comment: Will you ever have a column that is all -1 ? Your update, of course works, but it makes it less efficient. [except won't you need `else 0` instead of `else -1` ?]

Comment: Yes, it's possible - I got some `nan`s returned from the answer, so even though this is less efficient I thought it was necessary. I could use `else 0` but it makes sense in my context to have `else -1` because that is a numeric representation of an impossibility in my code (I can never have a negative mean).

Answer (score 2):

A solution without third-party libraries:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
from statistics import mean

def f(lst):
    return [mean(x for x in t if x != -1) for t in zip_longest(*lst, fillvalue=-1)]
```

```
>>> f(list_of_lists)
[0.37, 0.5866666666666667, 0.515, 0.10500000000000001, 0.9]
```

It uses [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) with `fillvalue` set to `-1` to "transpose" the list and set missing values to `-1` (will be ignored at the next step). Then, a generator expression and [`statistics.mean`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) are used to filter out `-1`s and get the average.

Comment: I should have mentioned in the question: I'm working with Python 2.7, and `zip_longest` only works in Python 3 as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas module to process.Code would like this :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

list_1 = [-1, 0.67, 0.23, 0.11,np.nan]
list_2 = [-1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]
list_3 = [0.54, 0.24, -1,np.nan,np.nan]
list_4 = [0.2, 0.85, 0.8, 0.1, 0.9]
df=pd.DataFrame({"list_1":list_1,"list_2":list_2,"list_3":list_3,"list_4":list_4})
df=df.replace(-1,np.nan)
print(list(df.mean(axis=1)))
```